# Restore Sharepoint 2007 from backup files on fresh installations

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007

I want to restore SharePoint 2007 from backup files (taken through Central Administration Site) with fresh installations of database and application server. Is it possible or not??

Regards
Madiha

Comment: make sure you have the same patches. otherwise, it may generate issues in the content database

Answer (score 0):

**WHAT TO RESTORE ?**

Firstly, we need to check, what all we need to restore.

When you do a fresh installation of database and application server, you will require to restore the content dbs, configuration db for Central Admin, the configuration setting changes in the Farm, like IIS settings, Email settings, Content Deployment settings,etc and other customizations made to web.config and web part deployments.

**Features supported by Central Admin Backup**

Now, when you say, backup taken from Central Administration, reading [this msdn article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287880%28v=office.12%29.aspx#recovery) helps you to identify what features would not be backed up. We can conclude that any configuration settings or Customizations won't be backed up.

**Restoring only works with a fully stopped farm**

And a backup of the configuration database and Central Administration content database should only be taken from a fully stopped farm for proper restore. If the configuration and Central Administration content databases of a farm become unsynchronized, you must re-create both databases by using the SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard or Psconfig command-line tool.

**Other methods**

You can use farm-level backups of a running farm taken with System Center Data Protection Manager to recover an entire farm, including the configuration database and Central Administration content database. [Full Details here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb795596.aspx).

Also [check out all other options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287880%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for a successful Farm backup and restore.